# Laravel 5 : what is @auth? is it shortcode?

Tags: laravel

What is @auth? is it shortcode ?
i seeing this code in welcome.blade.php

and where define this @auth code function ?

any idea please share.

Answer (score 2):

`@auth` is a blade directive used to show sections of template files to only users who are logged in.

Alternatively you can use `@guest` to show content to non-authenticated users only.

The code for what `@auth` is doing should be found in `src/Illuminate/View/Compilers/Concerns/CompilesConditionals.php` under the `compileAuth` method.

Comment: But where is this code that check to user is login or not , Andy ?

Comment: @Camit1dk it's essentially the same as `@if(Auth::check())`

Comment: @Camit1dk I've added the path for you

Comment: is there anywhere this code for check login or not using @auth ? it means to say where is this code define

Comment: @Camit1dk As my answer says, this is to show portions of a template to logged in users, it's not a login system. Look in the path for the method `compileAuth`

Comment: @Camit1dk, you may want to do more reading into MVC.  This is a view function to check if the user is logged in for display purposes,  actual authentication logic doesn't belong in the views (blade templates).  Once you have a better understanding of MVC, you may understand more of what this directive is for and why it exists.